# How to display quotes in HTML input value attributes without being susceptible to XSS injection?

Tags: php, html, xss

My html is not displaying quotes correctly inside of a value attribute in an input field. I have a form that shows the current value of a field stored in a database, and lets users edit that field.

below is what I have stored in a mysql database

```
'sarah' said "hello"
```

below is my retrieval and decoding from the database using PDO and htmlentities:

```
$questionId = intval($_GET['questionID']);
...
$sql = 'SELECT title from questions q WHERE q.id = :questionId';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':questionId' => $questionId));
...
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$questionTitle = htmlentities($row["title"], ENT_NOQUOTES);
...
echo <<<END
Question Title: <input type="text" id="questionTitle" name="questionTitle" placeholder="Enter question title here" maxlength="74" value="$questionTitle" required>
END;
```

What the page displays is the following:

```
Question Title:[[&#039;sarah&#039; said &quot;hello&quot;]]
```

where [[ ]] indicates an input box.

How do I get the input box display the quotes rather than the html entities? I want it to display the following

```
Question Title: [['sarah' said "hello"]]
```

If I do not use the htmlentities function to sanitize the output, then the question title displays as I want it to (with the quotes). But from what I understand, not escaping my HTML output would leave me vulnerable to an XSS injection. See this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

How do I display these quotes in the value attribute of my input field without being vulnerable to XSS injection?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're being returned as html entities. From the php manual:

```
string htmlspecialchars_decode ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 ] )
```

You've got htmlentities up there, so that could be why you're returning them. Try adding _decode to that and see what happens (or take that out entirely). So your line would look like this:

```
$questionTitle = $row["title"];
```

Comment: Right. Not using htmlentities makes it display correctly for me. BUT doesn't not using htmlentities mean I would be susceptible to XSS injection?

Comment: You should check out this answer here. Either way, if you encode the html going in, you would need to decode it coming back out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8975539/2374753

Comment: It's also unnecessary when you use prepare statements. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1219159/2374753

Comment: Janden, prepared statements prevent SQL injections, not XSS injections. Do you know how I can prevent my html output from being vulnerable from XSS injections?

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Try `code` echo htmlspecialchars(($row["title"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); `/code`